# Find repeated values in a list of sets elegantly

Tags: set, python-3.2

I have a problem where I am able to produce a list of sets and I am trying to find an elegant way to produce a set of the values that appear as repeats between the sets.

I've used counters to try to keep track of the values in sets, but I have a feeling there is a more optimal way to perform this activity.

For example, my program outputs

`[{8,6}, {3,6}, {8,4}]`

and I would like it to return to me

`{8,6}`

Thanks in advance!